# How to pass string object(std::string) using fifo?

Tags: c++, string, fifo

I tried to pass the string object using fifo.In write.cpp I am reading the input from the user and passing that input to as a reference parameter in write method.In read.cpp I am reading the data from read function.

**write.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int fd;
    string s1;
    mkfifo("f1",0664);
    fd = open("f1",O_WRONLY);
    if(fd<0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Enter the string \n";
    cin >> s1;
    cout << "length : " << s1.length() + 1;
    write(fd,&s1,s1.length() +1);
}
```

**read.cpp**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int fd;
    string r1;
    mkfifo("f1",0664);

    fd = open("f1",O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 0;
    }
    read(fd,&(r1),r1.length() + 1) ;
    cout << "length : " << r1.length() + 1;
    cout << r1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but after entering the string as input,the read side programming is terminated showing as the below error message

```
*** Error in `./read': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffc94630940 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fb514adb7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fb514ae437a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fb514ae853c]
./read[0x400e41]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fb514a84830]
./read[0x400c99]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 5785012                            /home//temp/read
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:07 5785012                            /home//temp/read
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 5785012                            /home//temp/read
007f9000-0082b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fb510000000-7fb510021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: You can't read and write non-POD c++ classes like this, you need to serialise their data manually

Comment: The linked I marked as duplicate uses `std::ostream` but the solution is exactly the same. You'll have to save the length of the string as well as its contents.

Comment: yes, I saw the answer to that question, but I am also using std::string only here not char *

Comment: @SwarajSomala, the answer suggests use of `std::string` and shows how to read/write `std::string`.

Comment: @R Sahu got it. Thank you!!!